# Firestore Security Rule: Check user input on get query

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm creating a blog with Firestore. I have two collections called `users` and `blogPosts`. Each document in `blogPosts` contains `name`, `createdAt`, `createdBy` and `password` (plain string) field.

I want to create a security rule so clients can access a document only if they provide the correct document `password`.

According to an idea in [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation), I wrote a rule like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /blogPosts/{postUid} {
        allow write: if 
            request.resource.data.createdBy == request.auth.uid &&
            request.resource.data.name is string &&
            request.resource.data.name.size() > 2 &&
            request.resource.data.name.size() < 32 &&
            request.resource.data.password is string &&
            request.resource.data.password.size() > 5 &&
            request.resource.data.password.size() < 32
      
        allow read: if 
            request.auth != null &&
            request.resource.data.password == resource.data.password // <---- THIS LINE IS NOT WORKING
    }
  }
}
```

I get this error in playground with the rule above: `Error: simulator.rules line [16], column [8]. Property resource is undefined on object.` So it means we don't have `resource.data` on `read` queries.

How can I achieve my goal with Firebase security rules, so only clients that has `blogPosts` password can access to documents?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do isn't possible with security rules (and also isn't really "secure" at all).  A client app can't simply pass along some password in a query.  The only time input is checked is for document fields in a write operation, not document reads.

If you want to check a password, you will have to make some sort of API endpoint and require that the caller provide the password to that endpoint.  Again, bear in mind that this is only as secure as your ability to keep that password a secret, because once it becomes known (perhaps by simply reverse engineering your app), anyone will be able to use it.

Comment: Thank you Doug! Btw, I watched all your Firecast videos on Youtube and they're great! Clients type passwords in a textbox and I send passwords through https channel so why it isn't secure? Currently, my client's implementations rely on Firestore SDK to read/write data to take advantage of offline sync. But now I have to create an API endpoint in Cloud Function to check passwords and return the document if the password is correct. Am I write?